# Conditional probability given multiple non-mutually exclusive prior events?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

All examples I've seen for predicting $P(B|A_1 \& A_2 \ldots \& A_n)$ assume that $A_1$, $A_2$, etc., are all mutually exclusive. What if I want to predict $B$ but have overlapping $A$'s?

For example:

```
B = it rains

given 

A1 = there are clouds in the sky
A2 = humidity level is over 80%
A3 = it is currently "the rainy season" 
A4 etc
```

Obviously, all of these $A$'s are not mutually exclusive.  How does one calculate $P(B|A_1 \& A_2 \ldots \& A_n)$ in this case?

Comment: In reality, the A's are usually not independent. The examples that I'm assuming you're referring to are those for which the A's are independent or that B is conditionally independent given the A's. This is done for mathematical simplicity or contrived examples or in some real, but narrow, examples. To solve your problem you need to solve a joint distribution - usually a difficult endeavor in practice.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Comment: The usual way to estimate something like this would be to fit a logistic regression model.

Answer (score 2):

To specifically answer your last question:

$$P(B|A_1,A_2, ..., A_n) = \frac{P(B, A_1, A_2, ...,A_n)}{P(A_1, A_2, ...,A_n)}$$

If you don't assume independence, then you have to calculate $P(B, A_1, A_2, ...,A_n)$ and $P(A_1, A_2, ...,A_n)$ both of which are joint distributions.

If you assume independence among the $A_i$'s then:

$$P(A_1, A_2, ...,A_n) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} P(A_i)$$

If you assume $B$ is conditionally independent given $A_i$'s then you can write:

$$\begin{aligned}P(B, A_1, A_2, ...,A_n) & = P(A_1, ..., A_n | B)P(B) \\ & = P(A_1|B)...P(A_n|B)P(B)\end{aligned}$$

Both of the above calculations are usually tractable and/or computationally much less expensive.

Comment: so you're saying that in real life many people assume independence even though they know the A's are not actually independent just for an easier calculation? Do you end up with much different probability estimates between assuming independence (even though there is no independence) and actually taking the time to calculate the joint distributions?

Comment: Absolutely. Google around for Bayes nets or Naive Bayes for an example of where this happens all the time. Sometimes the conditional assumption is ok to make so the calculation isn't too far off from the true joint.